# How to add \thanklessauthor to a KOMA Script document?

Tags: macros, koma-script, incompatibility, tufte

Well I'm working with a document in `KOMA Script` and I tried to use the `\thanklessauthor` command that I found in the code of the *Sample book* of `Tufte-book` class. First I thought it was a plain `TeX` macro, but it is not.

Searching a little in the web, I found [this page](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/58777075/) and between the lines 531 and 543 there is the part of the code that defines what I need. But it's strange for me don't see the whole definition of the `\newcommand` in each case. I never before programmed a class or something like, so I don't understand how is working that.

Until now, my MWE would be:

```
\documentclass[headsepline=true,paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,DIV=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[copyright]{ccicons}
\usepackage{bera}

%%%%%%% Page Style
\usepackage[nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

% Prints the month name (e.g., January) and the year (e.g., 2008)
\newcommand{\monthyear}{%
\ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or
  December\fi\space\number\year
}

\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing

%\usepackage[stable,bottom]{footmisc}
\raggedbottom
\clubpenalty=3000
\widowpenalty=3000
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\extratitle{\vspace*{4\baselineskip}\centering on the quiet}
    \titlehead{Opera Prima Collection}
    \title{Tales on the quiet}
    %\subtitle{}
    \author{Me}
    \date{}
    \publishers{\emph{Listopad}}
    \uppertitleback{
    Copyleft \ccShareAlike\ \the\year\ \thanklessauthor 

\textsc{Edited by \thanklesspublisher}   
}
    \lowertitleback{    
Design and typesetting: \emph{Listopad} \\    
\textit{First edition, \monthyear}.
}
    \dedication{To my thumb.}
    \maketitle    
\end{document}
```

So how could I add those commands to my document?

---

### Update

After the suggestions and the answer of Johannes B I try to adapt his suggestions to my code, this is the result of my MWE updated:

```
\documentclass[headsepline=true,paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,DIV=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Actually in the document is in Spanish
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[copyright]{ccicons}
\usepackage{bera}

%%%%%%% Style chapter adjustments

%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\@chapapp{}
%\renewcommand \thechapter{}
%\makeatother

%%%%%%% Page Style
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} %  If I add this line I've got two figures of rulers in the head and the foot, now not.
%\usepackage[nouppercase]{scrpage2}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}

% Prints the month name (e.g., January) and the year (e.g., 2008)
\newcommand{\monthyear}{%
\ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or
  December\fi\space\number\year
}

\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing

%\usepackage[stable,bottom]{footmisc} I want to know how to use the KOMA solution instead.
\raggedbottom
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\KOMAoption{parskip}{half}

%%%%%%%% Automation

\usepackage{xifthen}
\makeatletter
%JB Taken from tufte-common.def
\newcommand{\plainauthor}{}%
\newcommand{\thanklessauthor}{}%
\renewcommand*{\author}[2][]{%
    \gdef\@author{#2}%
    \begingroup%
    % TODO store contents of \thanks command%
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}%
    \protected@xdef\thanklessauthor{#2}%
\endgroup%
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
{\renewcommand{\plainauthor}{\thanklessauthor}}%
{\renewcommand{\plainauthor}{#1}}%
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\plainauthor}}}{}%
}%

\usepackage{xparse}

%Redefining the publishers
\RenewDocumentCommand{\publishers}{ o m o}{ % I didn't understood this line
    \def\publishernothanks{}
    \def\shortpublishers{}
    \IfValueTF{#3}{
        \gdef\@publishers{#2\thanks{#3}}
        \gdef\publishernothanks{#2}
        \gdef\publisherthanksnote{#3}
    }
    {
        \gdef\@publishers{#2}
        \let\publishernothanks\publishers
    }
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
        \let\shortpublishers\publishernothanks
    }{
        \gdef\shortpublishers{#1}
    }
}

\makeatother

%\addtokomafont{author}{\itshape}
%\addtokomafont{publishers}{\itshape}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\extratitle{\vspace*{4\baselineskip}\centering on the quiet}
\titlehead{State Fund for Culture and the Arts of Tabasco. \\
Cultural Institute of Tabasco}
\subject{Tales}
\title{ on the quiet}
%\subtitle{}
\author{Me}
\date{}
\publishers{\emph{Listopad}}
\uppertitleback{
    Copyleft \ccShareAlike\ \the\year\ \thanklessauthor 
\textsc{Edited by \thanklesspublisher}   
}
\lowertitleback{    
Design and typesetting: \thanklesspublisher \\    
\textit{First edition, \monthyear}.
}
\dedication{To my thumb.}
\maketitle    

\blinddocument
\chapter{Let's test the result}
\begin{labeling}{the thanklessauthor}
\item[The author] \makeatletter \@author \makeatother
\item[the thanklessauthor] \thanklessauthor
\item[the plainauthor] \plainauthor
\item[the publisher] \makeatletter\@publishers\makeatother
\item[the shortpublisher]\shortpublishers
\item[publishernothanks]\publishernothanks
\item[publishthanksnote]\publisherthanksnote
\end{labeling}
\end{document}
```

This MNWE (Minimal *not* working example) has errors, one of them is that I can't use `\thankslesspublisher` inside a `\uppertitleback` and `\lowertitleback`

Comment: Look at line 562 ff. You could simply copy the definition to your preamble, make sure not to forget the `\makeatletter ... \maketatother`-combi.
But to be honest, right now i don't know *why* you need this.

Comment: It's late here. Going to take a look at this in the morning. Please be patient, we'll find asolution ;-)

Comment: I understand, and don't worry this work isn't urgent. Thanks for the helping and the new tricks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tufte classes define an author command in a way, that a
thanks is gobbled and just the name is stored
(`thankslessauthor`). If an optional argument to `\author` was
given, this is stored as the `plainauthor`, if none was given,
`thanklessauthor` and `plainauthor` are the same.

As you can see on the last page of the example, if the *thanks*
is not gobbled, the footnotemark is output as well.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there might be a
more KOMA-like solution in stock.

For the publishers i used a different approach using package
`xparse`. You can use `\publishers` the regular way, but if you
want to
include a *thanks* you can put it in the optional argument at the
end. If you want to give an optional shortpublisher, you can use
the optional argument at the beginning. If none is given, the
*shortpublisher* will be the *publisher*.

Package `xparse` enables us to define commands with an advanced
syntax.
Defining `\RenewDocumentCommand{\publishers}{ o m o }{ <definition> }` we can use 
`\publishers[<optional short publisher>]{<publishers>}[<optional thanks>]`
in the document. The `{ o m o }` part defines, what arguments the
command can take. In this case an *o*ptional argument (the short
publisher), a *m*andatory argument (the publisher) and another
*o*ptional argument (a possible thanks).

The thanks is saved in the variable `\publisherthanks` if you
wish to later use it again.

You can change the appearance of the elements by adding
(`addtokomafont`, appends to the list) or setting (`setkomafont`,
resets the list and starts over) font  and size switches.

Package `scrlayer-scrpage` is the successor of `scrpage2`. The
global option `headsepline=true` is passed to the package
leading to a separation line between the head and the text body.

Concerning the footnotes, instead of using option `stable` KOMA
and also the standard classes provide the optional argument. The
KOMA-interface is more advanced here, you can choose different
titles for the head, the toc and the actual chapter title. 
The `bottom` option is not provided by KOMA, since the package
doesn't interfere with KOMA, it's fine to use.

```
\documentclass[headsepline=true,paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,DIV=10]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Actually in the document is in Spanish
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[copyright]{ccicons}


%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\@chapapp{}
%\renewcommand \thechapter{}
%\makeatother

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 

% Prints the month name (e.g., January) and the year (e.g., 2008)
\newcommand{\monthyear}{%
\ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or
  December\fi\space\number\year
}


%\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} 


\usepackage{xifthen}
\makeatletter
%JB Taken from tufte-common.def
\newcommand{\plainauthor}{}%
\newcommand{\thanklessauthor}{}%
\renewcommand*{\author}[2][]{%
    \gdef\@author{#2}%
    \begingroup%
    % TODO store contents of \thanks command%
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}%
    \protected@xdef\thanklessauthor{#2}%
\endgroup%
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
{\renewcommand{\plainauthor}{\thanklessauthor}}%
{\renewcommand{\plainauthor}{#1}}%
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\plainauthor}}}{}%
}%

\usepackage{xparse}

%Redefining the publishers

\RenewDocumentCommand{\publishers}{ o m o }{
    \def\publishernothanks{}
    \def\shortpublishers{}
    \def\publisherthanksnote{}
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{
        \gdef\@publishers{#2}
        \let\publishernothanks\@publishers
    }
    {
        \gdef\@publishers{#2\thanks{#3}}
        \gdef\publishernothanks{#2}
        \gdef\publisherthanksnote{#3}
    }
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
        \let\shortpublishers\publishernothanks
    }{
        \gdef\shortpublishers{#1}
    }
}
\makeatother
\publishers{Listopad}

%\addtokomafont{author}{\itshape}
%\addtokomafont{publishers}{\itshape}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\extratitle{\vspace*{4\baselineskip}\centering on the quiet}
\titlehead{State Fund for Culture and the Arts of Tabasco. \\
Cultural Institute of Tabasco}
\subject{Tales}
\title{ on the quiet}
%\subtitle{}
\author{Me}
\date{}
\uppertitleback{
    Copyleft \ccShareAlike\ \the\year\ \publishernothanks \\
    \textsc{Edited by \publishernothanks}
}
\lowertitleback{%
Design and typesetting:  \publishernothanks \newline
\textit{First edition, \monthyear}.
}
\dedication{To my thumb.}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle    

\blinddocument
\chapter{Let's test the result}
\begin{labeling}{the thanklessauthor}
\item[The author] \makeatletter \@author \makeatother
\item[the thanklessauthor] \thanklessauthor
\item[the plainauthor] \plainauthor
\item[the publisher] \makeatletter\@publishers\makeatother{}
\item[the shortpublisher]\shortpublishers
\item[publishernothanks]\publishernothanks
\item[publishthanksnote]\publisherthanksnote
\end{labeling}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting solution, in fact I also wanted to use the `\thankslesspublisher` command, so I review your solution and I added the code missing form that section of the code, but doesn't work, still doesn't appear on my document. Should I modify my MWE or edit my question for show that?

Comment: I added the functionality using a different approach. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the helping, the MWE runs fine. My problem is when I want to build a legal page using `\uppertitleback` and `\lowertitleback`, at least `\thankslesspublisher` can't run inside those macros. Maybe is because the definition of both them, I'm not sure but isn't serious.

Comment: @Aradnix I edited the answer. There was only *one* character missing, leading to a real big blow up. Took me a while to see the cause.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now it's late for me (3:22 am) and unfortunately I have a lot of work with my thesis right now, I think until the weekend I  could check properly your answer. Thanks again.